# PHP replace array value by key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [email_theme_id] => 1_5
            [email_template] => Array()
            [add_template] => 
            [email_template_subject] => Your free and bargain ebook alert for Sunday
            [last_update] => 1392314609
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [email_theme_id] => 2_12
            [email_template] => Array()
            [add_template] => 
            [email_template_subject] => Your free and bargain ebook alert for Sunday
            [last_update] => 1392314609
        )

)
```

and I need to change Array item [1] [email_template] value, so how should I do It with PHP?

Comment: You already answered your question u can use   item [1] [email_template] = "new data"

Comment: this is what hard work everyday do with our brain... thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
$item[1][email_template] = array('new value');
```

Or even you can do like

```
$item[1][email_template][0] = 'new value';
```

Considering that you want to update the array

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$data[1]['email_template'] = 'new value';
```

Where `$data` is your data variable.